# what does "in what " means here

Tags: grammar

In this sentence

> Anthony Scaramucci said he was invited to President Trump's farewell ceremony at Joint Base Andrews Wednesday, in what he says is a sign the White House is desperate for guests.

what does "in what" mean in this sentence? I know "in" is the preposition. in is referring "what he says"? Can someone explain to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help to answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267888/can-anyone-explain-the-use-of-in-what-in-the-following-sentence